# How to delete files using batch script in date wise (user input as date )

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off


::setting the local extensions

setlocal enableextensions
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

::setting the path and date 
:: %~dp0 this cmd fetch the path from where the script is running.(removed)


set /p path=Enter the path where the script has to be Run:
cd %path%
echo.%path%
echo. %date% %time% >>deletionlog.log

del *.* /s /q >null >>deletionlog.log

pause...
```

This is the **script** I was using but as I am new to batch script. 
I was unable to get the date from user and the files which are under that date should be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Extract from my backuping script:

set backupdir="%cd%"

set remove_old_after_days=14

forfiles -p %backupdir% -s -m *.zip /D -%remove_old_after_days% /C "cmd /c del @path"